# Force Photos.app to accept GPS coordinates & not "correct" them

Tags: photos, gps

I often need to tweak the GPS coordinates of images I take with my iPhone. Since I work on a MBP laptop, I do it there. A workflow: use a map app to find the precise location of the photo. Enter those coordinates into the location field in the Get Info box of the image. Watch Photos.app decide what I "meant" and move the coordinates to what it thinks is the closest place. This is often a what it thinks a city's coordinates are when I feed it a location inside that city.

The question then is how I make it stop doing this. I can move the pin, of course, or just use something like exiftool to edit the image's data directly, but it seems like this should be doable within Photos.

Then again...

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised it it's doing the same as it does for regular Map pins. You enter co-ordinates (or drop a pin) it says 'thank you very much' then proceeds to re-analyse it to the "nearest postcode". I've been filing bug reports on this for probably a decade. Still not fixed.

Comment: I was sure I'd had a proper rant about this on here somewhere, but it eludes me. All I can find is this - https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/351110/85275 which vaguely talks about how it stores/searches locations. I still have one address location from my old job a decade ago that to this day consistently navigates to a point 5 miles away, in a city centre. (I keep it around as a test to see if they ever fix this bug)

Comment: @Tetsujin It definitely knows about some specific locations, like museums, though the terminology for foreign places can be erratic (sometimes in the local language, sometimes in English on my English-language system).

Comment: Yup, it does. This is easiest to see in some out-of-the-way location like some big country stately home etc. It marks the castle etc on the map just fine, but you try dropping a pin at the car park entrance, then saving it as a contact ;)

Comment: Also just discovered that Photos treats changes to or creation of location data as an edit and stores it in its own internal database, but not in the file itself. So if you export the original file, it won't have the changed/added location. If you change the location in the original (say, via exiftool), Photos won't just read it in, but you'll see an option to "Revert to original location" in the Image/Location menu. Guess I'll be writing a script to push my Photos changes via exiftool. Awesome.

Comment: OK, I did write up [a few applescripts](https://github.com/Jmuccigr/AppleScripts/tree/master/Photos) to automate this, including pushing the Photos geolocation to the original file via exiftool and then having Photos read that back in, so that it knows that it's up to date with the original.

Comment: That looks worth putting in as an answer :))